# What constitutes a web application instance / session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is something I am unclear about.

Say I have SomeModule.dll

It has a static class called UserSession.

Could I for example, safely store user-specific information here:
Ex:

```
UserSession.Name = "xxx"
```

I know I can use HTTPConext.Session.... but I am wondering exactly the scope of a session/ Mainly, if the user has a prolonged session. Say the user logs on and I store some stuff in Session(user)...

If he comes bak in 3 weeks and I read a cookie of his and it is still valid, the page should look and feel like he never left. When does the HTTPContext or any session variables get erased and must be re-queried and reset?

Thanks

Comment: Storing values in a static field in a class is not the same as storing values in the session.  Static values are scoped per application instance, and session values are per user session.  This means that a static value can be read by every user of that application, so it is not a safe place to store user specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user session lasts only a certain amount of time from last request, I believe 20 minutes is the default. After that it may last a few more minutes depending on when the garbage collector does its thing. It will not last three weeks. You could store the necessary values in a cookie, or better cookie with a reference to a database record. However, all of this ignores security issues...

Comment: Session depends on Garbage Collector? Are you sure of that?

Comment: @Shai I could not find an online reference that answers this question. I believe it is correct based on previous readings. I just received the C# 5 book so soon I'll be able to update this answer as to whether this is correct...

Comment: Great. Thanks for the response. I would be very interested in the answer either way.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are not necessarily a good way to go regardless of the duration of time.  They add significant complexities when you are sclaing your application up to a web farm.  If it is non-sensitive data a cookie is the way to go.  If it is sensitive data of a larger amount of data, you may consider creating some sort of user authentication and/or encrypting cookie data.